# Importing Statsmodels LogisticGAM

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, gam

I have used and like the statsmodels.GLMGAM because of the nice output it produces with the summary table. I haven't seen a method of importing... I have tried
`from statsmodels.gam.api import LogitGAM` and looking within the gam class as it says it is here from the website: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.gam.generalized_additive_model.LogitGam.html#statsmodels.gam.generalized_additive_model.LogitGam

Comment: `import LogitGam` not Logistic, according to the doc link

Comment: thanks that was a typo, I have unfortunately tried `LogitGam` and `LogitGAM`

Comment: LogitGam is not in the `api` because it is a class purely based on inheritance and not a full GAM class like GLMGam. LogitGam needs to be imported directly from the module

Comment: Got it thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through searching on the statsmodels website and realising `LogitGam` was a class within as opposed to its own type of module you can get the below result.

`from statsmodels.gam.generalized_additive_model import LogitGam`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you did to solve the problem** and why you believe it is the best approach?